# Read ticker list from an external txt file

Tags: python

I've this simple python script that retrieve financial data from Yahoo Finance:

```
import yfinance as yf
tickers_list = ["aapl", "goog", "amzn", "BAC", "BA"] # example list
data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
print(data['Adj Close'])
```

[image]

I'd like to read tickers_list from an external file but if I create a script like this:

```
import yfinance as yf
fh = open("tickers.txt") # No need to specify the mode as READ is the default mode
tickers_list = fh.read()
data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
print(data['Adj Close'])
```

...anything goes wrong:
[image]

tickers.txt:

```
["aapl", "goog", "amzn", "BAC", "BA"]
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: print your `tickers_list` after you get from `tickers_list = fh.read()`. Most likely it is of type str, rather than list

Comment: also, remove the brackets and double quotes from the txt file. it should only be ```aapl, goog, amzn, BAC, BA```

Comment: Hi. akshayk. Removing brackets and double quotes, it works. Thansk

Answer (score 0):

`fh.read()` returns a string, not a list of strings

Here is code that should work:

```py
import yfinance as yf

with open("tickers.txt") as fh: # No need to specify the mode as READ is the default mode
    ticker_list = fh.read().splitlines()

data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")

print(data['Adj Close'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem is that `yf.download` expects the 1st arg to be a list but what you read from the file is a string. If you change your tickers file so that they are space-separated or one per line, then you can read them with

```
with open("tickers.txt") as fh:
    tickers_list = fh.read().split()
```

Of course, you can have the tickers be separated by some other character as long as you specify that to `split`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have the tickers as plain text in your `tickers.txt` file, not structured as you would write a Python `list`. Otherwise, it assumes each ticker literallly includes the quotes and the brackets.

```
aapl, goog, amzn, BAC, BA
```

Normally I would then tell you to split, but from the look of your error message [(which you should paste as text, not an image in the future)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) it appears that it is already able to split a string of comma separated values. In general though, I would recommend that you split it yourself manually with `.split(",")` and then use `.strip()` to ensure there are no errant whitespaces attached to your tickers.